# Why does std::map::operator[] assignment require an argumentless constructor?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, c++11, stdmap

I have the following minimal example reproducing an error in my code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

class B 
{
public:
    B(int b) : m_b{ b } {}
    int m_b;
};

int main()
{    
    using std::cout, std::endl;
    std::unordered_map<int, B> ab{};

    ab[1] = B(3);
    //ab.insert(std::pair<int, B>(1, B(3)));

    cout << ab[1].m_b << endl;
}
```

This fails with a long and unwieldy error which basically amounts to saying that there is no constructor for `B` without any arguments. The error stems from `ab[1] = B(3)` Why is that needed? And why does using `insert` instead of `operator[]` not need that constructor?

Bonus points for why this line in my original code:

```
Vec2 pos{ m_orbits[&p].positionAtTime(m_time + dt) };
```

also requires a non - parameterized constructor. I could not reproduce that error in my minimal example, but `m_orbits` is an unordered map with pointers to `Particle` objects as keys and `Orbit` objects as values. `positionAtTime` is a `const` member function of `Orbit` that calculates the position of a particle in the orbit at a certain time.

Comment: You can't assign (call operator=) without having a instance created (on the left side) first.

Comment: What should `ab[1]` return when `ab` is an empty map?

Comment: `ab[1] = B(3)` fails because `unordered_map::operator[]()` inserts an default-constructed element into the map if one isn't already there (for the supplied key).   To do that, it needs to default a `B`.   A reference to the corresponding `B` in the map (whether just constructed or previously there) is returned.    In `ab[1] = B(3)`,  that referred-to `B` is then assigned the result of `B(3)`.       There is no shortcut for the above based on knowing the right-hand side is a `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is [a constructor for `B` without any arguments] needed?

This is because [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) required the `mapped_type` (i.e. in your case `B`)  to be default constructable.

> 1. Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist. This function is equivalent to return `insert(std::make_pair(key, T())).first->second`;
>
>    - `key_type` must meet the requirements of *CopyConstructible*.
>    - **`mapped_type` must meet the requirements of *CopyConstructible* and *DefaultConstructible*.**
>      If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

When you provide a user defined constructor (i.e. `B(int b)`), the [compiler will not generate a default constructor automatically](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor), and thereby `A` can not be default construable.

> If some user-declared constructors are present, the user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default.

Hence, the above error!

---

> why does using `insert` instead of `operator[]` not need that constructor?

Because [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) relies on the `value_type` (i.e. `std::pair<const Key, T>`). For your `ab` this is `std::pair<const int, B>`. From the *cppreference.com* the function overloads:

> 1-3) Inserts value. The overload (2) is equivalent to `emplace(std::forward<P>(value))` and only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_constructible<value_type, P&&>::value == true`.
>
> 4-6) Inserts value in the position as close as possible, just prior(since C++11), to hint. The overload (5) is equivalent to `emplace_hint(hint, std::forward<P>(value))` and only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_constructible<value_type, P&&>::value == true`.

So as long as `B` is constructable the `std::pair<const int, B>` also can be constructed and `std::map::insert` can be work.